# Cannot run Fiware tutorial on github

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to run the tutorial on https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Time-Series-Data but I can't. Cygwin gives me the following error when I run `./services create:`

```
$ ./services create
./services: line 16: $'\r': command not found
: invalid option 17: set: -
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [--] [-] [arg ...]
./services: line 18: $'\r': command not found
./services: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token $'{\r''
'/services: line 30: loadData () {
```

It seems like the script has

```
 Windows-style line endings (\r\n or carriage return + line feed) which are causing the problems. I tried the command "dos2unix ./services" but getting the following error: 
': not a valid identifierort:
```

I've even tried wsl with Ubuntu and Alpine distros but still the same `error:  ': not a valid identifierort:`

I am running out of options at this stage so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [tutorial documentation](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

> The NGSI-v2 tutorials are designed to run under any **Unix environment**,
> the tested configuration and GitPod environment is currently based on
> Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. However, there may be some minor issues when
> running the tutorials directly on Windows machines or Apple M1 Silicon
> amd64 systems, and the following [Virtual Box
> set-up](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/virtual-box.html)
> or [WSL
> set-up](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wsl.html)
> can be used when facing issues.

You can verify this by running the tutorial using [GitPod](https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Time-Series-Data/tree/NGSI-v2) directly on a virtual Unix system.

It seems to me that the version you have locally on your Windows box has altered line endings some how - maybe you viewed a file and the editor "corrected" it for you by mistake? You can rectify these issues using the `dos2unix` utility.

```bash
dos2unix provision-devices
dos2unix import-data
```

... and repeat on any other file that is still not working for you.

Comment: I setup wsl with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, docker v20.10.14 and docker compose  v2.17.2 on Windows 10. I run ./services start as root and everything seems to be working fine. I run the first three cUrl requests with success but when I run requests 4 and onwards, I get error:  curl -X GET \
>   'http://localhost:8668/v2/entities/Lamp:001/attrs/luminosity?limit=3' \
>   -H 'Accept: application/json' \
>   -H 'Fiware-Service: openiot' \
>   -H 'Fiware-ServicePath: /'
{
  "description": "No records were found for such query.",
  "error": "Not Found"
}

Comment: This will be because you haven't switched on Lamp001, so no data has been sent. From the docs:

`For the purpose of this tutorial, we must be monitoring a system where the context is periodically being updated. The dummy IoT Sensors can be used to do this. Open the device monitor page at http://localhost:3000/device/monitor and unlock a Smart Door and switch on a Smart Lamp. This can be done by selecting an appropriate command from the drop-down list and pressing the send button. The stream of measurements coming from the devices can then be seen on the same page`

Comment: Well, I unlocked the door and switched on a lamp and it worked! The only problem I am having now is with Grafana. I can't find the below settings, the reason being a different version of Grafana: 
Click on Visualisation tab on the left and set as follows:

Map Layers:
Lamp:
Icon: lightbulb-o
ClusterType: average
ColorType: fix
Column for value: value
Maker color: red